# Can't compile QEMU on Mac OS X; says something about a previous declaration of uint16

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, compilation, qemu, darwin

When I try to compile QEMU on Mac OS X (I'm on Lion, but it happened on Snow Leopard as well) it gives me an error message about uint16. You can find the full output at [this link](http://pastebin.com/G076NiM0), as it's too long to paste here (scroll down to the bottom to see the errors.) Can anyone please tell me how to fix this, preferably without changing the source code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define uint16 to type qemu_uint16 in qemu/fpu/softfloat.h:

```
 typedef uint8_t flag;
+#ifdef __APPLE__
+#define uint16 qemu_uint16
+#endif
 typedef uint8_t uint8;
 typedef int8_t int8;
 #ifndef _AIX
```

The lines beginning with the + sign are the ones you need to add.

See here:  http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2011-10/msg03794.html